# if statement not working in javascript,is the syntax correct?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

This js script is not working for me, What am i doing wrong? is my syntax correct ?

```
$(document).on("click","."+deletebutton,function(){
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    if(id){
            if(p_name!= name){
        if(confirm("say something"))
            ajax("rid="+id,"del");
            }
            else{window.alert(say something);
            }
    }
});
```

Comment: what does `not working` mean? What do you expect? What do you observe instead? you do have a syntax error in the alert

Comment: Use [JSHint](http://jshint.com) if you’re getting syntax errors instead of asking on SO.

Comment: Missing quotes in the `alert()`

Comment: Also, don't see `p_name` or `name` defined anywhere.

Comment: the variables are defined ,  when i say not working, i mean it does not execute at all. I will check that syntax error @ xufox, if it bothers you that i asked , then why answer ? dont be arrogant

Comment: browser console errors will already tell you you have a syntax problem .. and where it is

Comment: @Xufox provided you with valuable advice about ways to find syntax errors, that are quicker and more efficient than asking on SO. Why on earth would you consider that to be arrogant?

Answer (score -1):

This is your code:

```
$(document).on("click", "." + deletebutton, function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    if(id)
    {
        if(p_name != name)
        {
            if(confirm("say something")) ajax("rid=" + id, "del");
        }
        else
            window.alert(say something);
    }
});
```

There is no quotes: `window.alert(say something);`.
Use `alert("say something");` instead.

And, are `deletebutton`, `name`, `p_name`, `ajax` defined?

Comment: yes they are defined, now that i corrected the quotes the script executes but the else statement will not execute

Comment: @user5420896 What does _the else_ mean exactly? Of the if-else statement?

Comment: this function deletes a row from a table, the if portion is saying if the person selecting the row is not the person who created it then a acknowledgment of the row being selected is shown, the else portion is gonna say , "you can not select this because you created it" .. thats the function in a detail, im intentionally disclosing as little as i can due to the fact that this is a function on a site

Comment: @user5420896 If you fixed the missing of quotes, the syntax is correct. Hmm.. Put `console.log("entry");` to check if the if-else statement works correctly. And check if ajax(...); works correctly..

Comment: <script> var name = '<?php echo $_SESSION['name']; ?>'; var p_name = '<?php echo $_SESSION['p_name']; ?>'; </script> <script src="js/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: deleted a comment; sorry nvm the comment.